# Communicating with devices from PC

Tags: usb, power-electronics, pc

For a few years, I have been using microcontrollers to do simple hobby projects that require using various communication protocols (serial, i2c) and toggling GPIO pins.  However, the computational capacity of microcontrollers is no longer sufficient for the projects I want to do.  Hence, I am looking for (if it exists) some kind of USB peripheral that has external pins similar to an Arduino's (e.g. PWM, rx/tx, I2C, etc.), but which can be controlled directly from a script running on my desktop or laptop.  In other words, I just want to use it as an interface between a PC and other electronic devices.  Do such things exist, and if so, what are they called?  Ideally, I would like to be able to control the hypothetical device with Python (perhaps using pyserial).  An absolute requirement in what I am looking for is the ability to communicate with Dynamixel motors, which use half-duplex TTL.

Thanks in advance for suggestions!

Comment: I think my comment about memory was misleading, so I've edited the post.  As to your suggestion, I am not sure I quite understand.  No matter what software I use, I still ultimately need a physical connection between my computer and my devices.  For a simple example, how would one provide a PWM signal to a DC motor from a PC?  Or communicate with an I2C device from a PC?  If my wiring is to be PC <--> ? <--> actuator/sensor, what are my options for the ?.

Comment: What is your specs? I mean specify at least three: 1. speed, 2. medium (voltage/current/light/sound/smoke signals) 3. desired protocol. You can not go anywhere without clear spec.

Comment: As with many *microcontrollers*, I am looking for something general purpose.  In other words, I would like to be able for it to communicate with other devices using various protocols (e.g. serial, I2C, etc.).  The same goes for medium.  On the other end, I want it to connect to my computer via USB.  Speed is not a major concern.  Am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Don't the various models or Arduino do exactly what you want? You certainly can send and receive data over the USB/Serial port and you can design it to respond to any command protocol you want.

Comment: Today's circuits, USB-etc, are much too fast to build by hand. So you need to be a skilled board designer and know the IC's that will work for you. You might be a wee bit in over your head here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select from many USB-to-desired_protocol modules.
The simplest is [USB-serial](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12731) based on FTDI chip.  Good made ones give you a possibility to control many or all of full RS-232 named pins.
Also, check [USB-I2C](https://www.robot-electronics.co.uk/htm/usb_i2c_tech.htm) module, or
[USB-to-SPI](https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/Microchip/ADM00421/?qs=%2Fha2pyFaduj%252bHRjS3wAv6404Kff1yVNvbznWCaadoA1%252bhgHIo9ckDw%3D%3D) module, or
[USB-to-I2C,SPI and serial](https://www.robotshop.com/uk/devantec-usb-i2c-spi-serial-interface.html)

Comment: Thanks!  This is very helpful, particularly the last link!

Answer (score 0):

There are USB to gpio/spi/i2c bridges out there that do a fraction of what you want. FTDI makes them.

But what you really want is a microcontroller. Like the arduino uno or higher power arm or cortex or other types of microcontrollers or System on chips. You then program the features you would control from the computer.

An alternative is the Raspberry Pi and it's clones or superior copies. These are full computer system on chips intended for hobbyist gpio control.

Comment: Can you explain your answer a bit more?  Why do I want a microcontroller if all I am seeking to do is control, say, a motor from my PC.  Isn't a microcontroller overkill for that job?  For example, is it even possible to control the pins of an RPi in real time with a script running on a PC?  I read somewhere that this is not an intended use of the RPi...

Comment: Your question made it seem like you wanted more than just a gpio. For just a motor, maybe, but a microcontroller can do the usb to gpio bridging. As for the rpi, you can control them almost in real time as the Linux on it is not a RTOS. It's 100% the intended use of a RPi, a commercial product targeting the hobbyist market created by the Arduino.

Comment: I thought the purpose of an RPi was to be programmed and then run autonomously, without connection to a PC.  Are you saying that it is just as easy to run a program on a PC and have it affect the RPi pins through a USB cable?  I apologize if I am belaboring the point, this is just counter to what I have read previously, and I want to confirm that I am understanding your comment correctly.

Comment: @AriHerman The RPi IS a computer. That happens to have GPIO, I2C, SPI, analog inputs, etc, broken out so they can be easily accessed. You can control the RPi directly. Or you can use it as a network appliance (IE a web server or SSH) that does what you need. Some clones also have USB OTG support, so you can connect them as usb devices.

Comment: I suppose the only question I have left is whether there is a compelling reason to use an RPi or microcontroller rather than an AxiCat or other adapter for what I want to do?

Comment: The axicat is an ATmega microcontroller based solution. It waa just designed by someone else. So you have less control than if you would make it yourself. But you have the benefit of not designing from scratch.

Comment: Okay, I see.  I probably am going to go with something that I don't need to design from scratch.  Thanks!